# Change button on hover/active

Tags: html, css

Hi there I have this button that has been driving me crazy!

Here is the [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M2f9F/30/)

HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    /* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: Transparent;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border: none;

    cursor:pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline:none;
    text-shadow:none !important;
    box-shadow:none !important;



}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropbtn:hover
{
  text-color: black;
}
```

As you can see when the button is clicked or currently showing the child links it is green! I'm trying to make it transparent so only the text shows.

I thought it was a :hover or :active but that never seemed to work so I have no idea what is causing it to turn green or how I can fix this. Any help?

Comment: so you want it transparent... `.dropdown:hover { background-color: transparent; }`.

Comment: ... I'm blind. Thank you

Comment: @JonathanZúñiga : you should put that as an answer in order to let him chose your answer and close the question.

Comment: You have been given 2 correct answers. You should consider accepting one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

Should be

```
.dropdown:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it solid - use a couple pseudo-classes

```
.dropdown:hover,
.dropdown:focus,
.dropdown:active {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```